# Should a concrete class that implements an interface have extra public methods for testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, oop

When implementing an interface on a concrete class, is it appropriate to have extra public methods exposed to help facilitate unit tests?

For example, let's say I have the following concrete class:

```cs
public class MyClass : IMyInterface
{
    public int InterfaceMethod(ComplexObject complexObject)
    {
        return NonInterfaceMethodOne(complexObject) 
            + NonInterfaceMethodTwo(complexObject);
    }

    public int NonInterfaceMethodOne(ComplexObject complexObject)
    {
        //Do complex logic that needs to be unit tested
    }
    public int NonInterfaceMethodTwo(ComplexObject complexObject)
    {
        //Do more complex logic that needs to be unit tested
    }
}
```

If I wrote my class this way, I could have unit tests for both non-interface methods, but I feel like this pattern is not correct. Is there a better way?

Comment: The answer to your title is "yes, there are many cases where a class may have methods that aren't defined on interfaces it implements". I think your question is more "Should I add public methods to a class just for the purpose of testing?".

Comment: @JoeSewell Thanks, updated the title.

Comment: Is the idea to make these private once they are tested as they will only be used within the class? You want to be careful because it is generally best practice to give public access to only want's needed. I would say if it's just for your own testing and in production they will be turned private that is fine.

Comment: Might this be a better fit for [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)? It compiles and works fine; you're asking if it's "correct". On the whole though, I'd say never expose anything that shouldn't be exposed, even if it's an admirable specimen.

Comment: Maybe instead of `public` use `internal` for something that you want to expose for unit testing, but isn't meant to be part of the actual public API of the class?

Comment: @juharr, This is the route I have taken. For anyone wondering, I updated the AssemblyInfo.cs and added the [InternalsVisibleToAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8) class.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there looks perfectly acceptable to me. A general answer to your question is "it depends," because there could be scenarios where you want to hide those methods, and there could be scenarios where you want to expose them.

It's reasonable to consider your test suite as the first client of your code base, and it makes sense to support the needs of your client--you would still want to give careful consideration to what functionality you want to expose and hide.

In spite of the fact that `NonInterfaceMethodOne` and `NonInterfaceMethodTwo` are both public, if you inject this implementation into a parameter of the interface type, the client will still only have access to the interface method and will have no knowledge of the other 2 methods.

A client that is using the implementation will of course have access to all 3 methods, but will still not know how the interface method is implemented.

If it would be useful to expose those methods for unit testing and if you can determine that no damage is done by keeping the methods public, then keep them public.

But, it could still be appropriate to write your tests to ensure that `NonInterfaceMethodOne` and `NonInterfaceMethodTwo` work the way you want, then cover your interface method with another test(s), and then you may possibly no longer have a need for the unit tests covering `NonInterfaceMethodOne` and `NonInterfaceMethodTwo`--in which case you could remove these tests, and then make `NonInterfaceMethodOne` and `NonInterfaceMethodTwo` private--because your unit test(s) covering the interface method covers the other 2 methods.

- and if you find that this approach doesn't hide any functionality that your test suite needs, I would lean toward this approach, because it's normally good to limit the functionality you expose

Answer (score 1):

You can get something similar to this, but without having to make the members public, by using the [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute?view=netframework-4.8).

Let's say your assemblies/projects are named `ProductCode.dll` and `TestFixtures.dll`. You can make the `internal` types and members in `ProductCode.dll` visible to `TestFixtures.dll`, but no other assemblies, by declaring the following in the `ProductCode` project (typically in `AssemblyInfo.cs`):

```cs
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestFixtures")]
```

Then you can declare these exposed-for-testing-only methods as `internal` instead of `public`, but the unit tests can still call them.

If you only run your tests in a Debug configuration, not in the Release configuration, you can make this access control exemption only happen in the Debug configuration by surrounding the attribute like this:

```cs
#if DEBUG
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("TestFixtures")]
#endif
```